# Deprecated classes in WebRTC

Tags: ios, webrtc

I am working on app that uses webrtc library of 2013. Now I am upgrading it to 2016 webrtc version. I am not able to compile and build my custom library as few class files which are used in my library are not present in current 2016 code base of webrtc.

Where to check changes in classes for webrtc?

Comment: see this once `https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios and https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about a specific library rather than about the WebRTC api. There's been lots of changes, but AFAIK no *classes* have been deprecated in the WebRTC API since 2013.